# How to Display NavBar Control Devexpress from Database

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle11g, devexpress, navbar

I have table MENU like this

[image]

GROUPMENU is a group in navbar control and JUDULMENU is an item. I have tried to using this code but it doesn't work

```
if (koneksidb.con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    koneksidb.con.Close();
koneksidb.con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM MENU ORDER BY GROUPMENU ASC";
cmd.Connection = koneksidb.con;
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

// Create a NavBarControl.
NavBarControl navBar = new NavBarControl();
this.Controls.Add(navBar);
navBar.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
// Apply the "SkinExplorerBarView" style.
navBar.PaintStyleName = "SkinExplorerBarView";

while (dr.Read())
{
    NavBarGroup groupLocal = new NavBarGroup(dr["GROUPMENU"].ToString());
    NavBarItem itemInbox = new NavBarItem(dr["JUDULMENU"].ToString());

    navBar.BeginUpdate();
    navBar.Groups.Add(groupLocal);
    groupLocal.ItemLinks.Add(itemInbox);
    groupLocal.Expanded = true;
    navBar.EndUpdate();
}
```

This the detail of my code Work:

[image]

Please anyone suggest me how to fix this code?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in MENU table just using query to separate between group and item.. it can use from different method or single method.. here is the example code to solve the problem above using single method:

```
try
{
    navBarControl1.BeginUpdate();

    //GET GROUP
    if (koneksidb.con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        koneksidb.con.Close();
    koneksidb.con.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT DISTINCT GROUPMENU FROM MENU ";
    cmd.Connection = koneksidb.con;
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        List<string> header = new List<string>();
        header.Add(dr["GROUPMENU"].ToString());

        foreach (string hdr in header)
        {
            NavBarGroup group = new NavBarGroup(hdr);
            //group.Caption = fi.Name;
            group.LargeImageIndex = 0;
            group.Expanded = true;

            //GET ITEM
            OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand();
            cmd1.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM MENU WHERE GROUPMENU='" + hdr + "' ORDER BY GROUPMENU ASC";
            cmd1.Connection = koneksidb.con;
            OracleDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr1.Read())
            {
                List<string> JudulLists = new List<string>();
                JudulLists.Add(dr1["JUDULMENU"].ToString());

                foreach (var Judul in JudulLists)
                {
                    NavBarItem item = new NavBarItem(Judul.ToString());
                    navBarControl1.Items.Add(item);
                    group.ItemLinks.Add(item);
                }
            }

            if (group.ItemLinks.Count > 0)
            {
                navBarControl1.Groups.Add(group);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    navBarControl1.EndUpdate();
}
```

The Result:

[image]

This solve for me now.. thanks